# wrong app_name displaying on shortcut

Tags: android, zxing

I am actualy integrating barcode scanner (ZXing) as a library in my application so the user don't need to download the BarcodeScanner app and I can add a few use case.

I have no functional issue and my application is working as expected but the name displayed under my shortcuts on the smartphone are those of the library : "Barcode Scanner"

I tried to change my android:label of my application so the compiler can't mix up the app_name of my string/app_name and the one of ZXing's string/app_name. I even modified the strings file of the library to delete the "app_name" element...

I tried to delete the intent filter...

```
<action android:name="code android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="code android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

...in the BarcodeScanner library's Manifest but it did not resolved anything.

Any hint on the way this app name is beeing retreived ?

Thank you.

PS : I noticed that my com.google.zxing.client.R.java still contains a "app_name" id even if I deleted it in the strings file.

Comment: try clean all project and built

Comment: I tried this also and it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out, my app didn't have a values-nl folder in ./res. The barcode scanner project did so it localized the app with that file and in that file is a app_name = Barcode Scanner.

I copied the /res/values folder to /res/values-nl and now it shows my app name and the scanner tool is still localized.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My application had the name of a library. I had to add a values-de folder in ./res, then the correct name was used again

Answer (score 2):

This is because you copied and pasted our whole app, rather than start by writing your own app, decide what you need to reuse, understand the code, and import what you want correctly. Copying like this is *strongly* discouraged, and if you're copying our UI and probably leaving most of the other elements unchanged, likely violates trademark law. Please delete your copy of our app from `android/` and start again. You want to write your app without the scanning, then, create a `SurfaceView` placeholder in your scan UI. Then import `core.jar` and reuse `DecodeHandler` for scanning if you like.

Comment: Understood.
Just note that this is just a temporary version to show what our app will be able to do. We just did not want our alpha users to download the Barcode scanner app to test it. Do not worry for the trademarks.
Thank you for this answer, that was not what I asked but it's true that I did not had a real idea of what I should do afterward.
I found how to correct what went wrong on the app name, there was more that one strings files in the barcode scanner app and I did not changed all of them.

Comment: Well I don't use your UI just some classes , but I coped whole thing as well and head this problem... I'd like to have it this way because I can update that low level stuff easily. Cool would be to have just library separated from barcode scanner application...  Anyway thank you for this library.

Comment: The scanning is already packaged as the library `core/`. Intent-based integration is packaged as `android-integration/`. `android/` is an app, not a library, and can't really be a library. Well, really that's exactly what the Intent integration is...

Answer (score 1):

In the *res* folder there are a lot of values-[language code] folders containing a *strings.xml* file, try changing the **app_name** value in those files.

But I would go with what Sean said.

Cheers.